# Cumulative Thesis/Dissertation

Tags: publications, phd, thesis, publishers

I am writing my PhD thesis now and my supervisor said it can be in the cumulative way because I've got enough papers, 3 in sum. So now I look for publisher permission to reprint the papers. My university uploads every thesis after it is defended to the university database, which is open access for everyone.

I got a little bit scared that I won't get the permission from Taylor & Francis, where my first paper is published, so the first chapter of my thesis is published. They need 6-8 weeks to answer, maybe more. So has anyone made some experience with permission to reprint their papers in cumulative thesis?

The other paper I use is published with Sage, and they say on their website, that it is possible to use the whole finale PDF in the thesis.

Is it common to just include the original paper PDFs in the thesis?

Comment: Worst case you cannot put "your" article in the public available thesis, and you must put a link to the original article only, where chapter x consists of one sentence "the publisher did not give explicit consent to republish here the paper *xxyyzz* I authored. The paper can be found at doi:xxcsacsacas".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Why are you scared? You should read the relevant guidelines of the publisher. This is a non-issue.

[Taylor & Francis explicitly state](https://authorservices.taylorandfrancis.com/publishing-your-research/moving-through-production/copyright-for-journal-authors/):

> After assigning copyright, you will still retain the right to:
>
> - ...
> - Include your article in your thesis or dissertation.
> - ...

Study the [article sharing guide](https://authorservices.taylorandfrancis.com/research-impact/sharing-versions-of-journal-articles/) or ask the publisher to find out which version of your manuscript you should include in your thesis if your library puts the thesis into an online repository.

A "cumulative thesis" is not something unusual and publishers have learned to accommodate it.

Comment: So in fact, T&F has *already* given permission to include the paper in the thesis, and OP does not need to put in a request or wait 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @NateEldredge they seem to have given permission to include it yes, but not to also make the thesis and so, by extension, the paper freely available to anyone to download online. That may or not be allowed.

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for the publisher, but expect it to be fine. You may have been given an explicit license when you published with T&F and these usually include permission for exactly what you want to do.

I'd proceed in the short term as if it is going to be permitted, writing the other needed parts to complete the whole while you wait for their answer to an enquiry.

But, clear this with your advisor.

It is likely that the publisher will want you to use the same exact paper that was published (the PDF) rather than a different version. A different version would complicate things.